# Self evaluating Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please help me to understand this in javascript how this works fine?

```
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable

    myEvent(chkevent, function(e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
        var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure to leave the page?';  // a space
        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
        return confirmationMessage;
    });
```

I understand the other parts of the script but not the `(e || window.event).returnValue` how thus it will be evaluated? does it means if `e` is true then its property `returnValue` will be set else it will use the `window.event`?

NOTE: Please guide me with the right title for this question as I don't know how this kind of javascript coding pattern is called

Comment: can anyone give a better title for this?

Comment: I would end up using your title as a platform to convey anti-Internet Explorer feelings, so I'll leave it to someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means:

```
e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;
```

and if not `e`

```
window.event.returnValue.confirmationMessage;
```

Consider the output of this snippet:

```js
var a = {}; 
var b = undefined;
var c = {}; 

(b || a).first = 'First!';
(c || a).second = 'Second!'; 

console.log(a); 
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

```
Object { first: "First!" }   // <-- a
undefined                    // <-- b
Object { second: "Second!" } // <-- c
```

In the line `(b || a).first = 'First!';`, b evaluates falsy to a is evaluated, is truthy, and so `a.first` is defined.

In the line `(c || a).second = 'Second!';`, c evaluates truthy and so `c.second` is defined. Note that `a.second` is not defined, because JavaScript's || short circuits.

The reason for the particular code you've posted to exist is due to Internet <s>Exploder's</s> Explorer's older versions.

Comment: I love the Internet Exploder XD and would accept this answer because of humor XD

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to be real here. The biggest reason why this code is so *strange* is Internet Explorer, and cross-browser compatibility issues.

The specific line you are referring to uses the JavaScript *OR* operator `||`, which basically returns the first element that is defined (or non-false). So, in this case, if the browser passes the argument `e` to the event handler, then it will be used, otherwise `window.event` is used.

Notice the parenthesis in `(e || window.event)`. This tells the engine to evaluate the *OR* operator *before* doing anything with the result. This makes sense because you want to access `e.returnValue` if `e` is defined, and `window.event.returnValue` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Yes :)

if `e` is "true" (not null, valid object), then it will return `e.returnValue` otherwise `window.event.returnValue`

Answer (score 0):

All that code is doing is providing a cross-browser solution to getting the event that just occured. This is because older versions of IE don't pass in the Event object to the event handler and instead set `window.event` which can only be accessed from an event handler. To be more precise:

So it first checks if `e` is set. If it is set than the code in the parenthesis returns the value of `e` and then grabs the value of `e.returnValue`. If `e` is not set then the parenthesis returns `window.event` and then grabs the value of `window.event.returnValue`.

If you want to know more about the `window.event` object you can read up on it here.
[Event Object IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)